# .NET native support of NoSQL

Tags: sql, .net, nosql

I am messed up with the data access technologies of .NET Framework.

Is it correct, that .NET **natively** only supports SQL-Databases, providing ADO.NET? Are there other natives ways of accessing relational databases?

NoSQL-Databes are only supported through extensions developped by community, like the MongoDB C# driver?

Answer (score 2):

ADO.NET is a technology for accessing relational databases only. It doesn't support any databases which are not queried through SQL.

There are some NoSQL databases (like CouchDB) which can be accessed through web services which the .NET framework can handle without 3rd party libraries. But even for CouchDB I would recommend you to use [the SharpCouch utility class](http://code.google.com/p/couchbrowse/source/browse/trunk/SharpCouch/SharpCouch.cs), which makes it much easier to use.

Theoretically you could access any database (SQL or not) using pure network sockets. Databases aren't black magic. When you get the documentation of the on-the-wire protocol of a database, you could implement that protocol yourself. But why reinvent the wheel when you can just download an already working database driver?

Answer (score 0):

NosDB ([An Open Source NoSQL Database](http://www.alachisoft.com/nosdb/)) provides [ADO.NET support](http://www.alachisoft.com/nosdb/adonet-support.html) if that helps you

From ADO.NET Integration Page

> By using the NosDB ADO.NET provider, you can migrate your existing relational database access code to NosDB very easily. Additionally, you can continue to use your favorite third-party tools and controls in your application because they’re also able to access NosDB database through ADO.NET.